# How to serialize and deserialize data from third party library objects for communication between C++ and Haskell?

Tags: haskell, serialization, c++17, deserialization, communication

I'm looking for a way to serialize and deserialize data for communication between c++ (Windows) and Haskell (Unix).

One of them is having to serialize and deserialize objects of types defined by third-party libraries used by C++. If I know the data inside the object, I can use JSON or protocol buffer, but I can't because I don't know the information inside the object.

The purpose of doing this is to delegate heavy computation from C++ to Haskell and return the result. Are there any libraries that can serialize and deserialize objects whose internals are unknown? Also, the following must be satisfied:

- It covers tens of MB of data.
- It should be fast.

Thank you.

---

###### Addition #1

The communication method I plan to use is web HTTP protocol. However, it is not necessarily limited to this method.

###### Specific example

I am a 3D programmer. I want to reduce the modeling operation time. And I have a high-performance PC available and I want to take advantage of it. I'm using a commercial library for modeling and I'm looking for a **way to fully convey this data**. (between C++ and Haskell)

The composition of the data is as follows.

```
{
  // My Data,
  // Third-party type data (3D object data; inside unknown)
}
```

Comment: No, of course you can't deserialize a bytestring if you don't know anything about the structure it represents. Do you have a more specific example of the kind of thing you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually it _might_ be possible to apply heuristics to get something like this working (based on things like "does this w64 represent a valid address"), but it seems like it will always be ugly, hackish and unreliable. At any rate, to get good answers you'd need to provide some more information about what kind of communication you're trying to set up here.

Comment: That doesn't really narrow it down, though. What do you mean by "convey" the data? Describe the full system (or a mockup example of a simplified but representative system), and who conveys what to whom for which purpose.

Comment: Do you mean you just want the Haskell code to haul around blobs of binary data that it otherwise doesn't understand? On the Haskell side, that's just a `ByteString`. If you're sending it over HTTP, you could e.g. just tack the blob onto the end of a JSON response... `aeson` at least looks capable of understanding that. There doesn't need to be any real (de)serialization of the binary data involved. I suggest you actually *try something* and come back when/if you have a *concrete* problem.